# The use of the function strchr

Tags: c++

I have met  a probleme about the use of the function `strchr`, my code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char linebuf[1000];
int main()
{

  char linebuf[] = "sortie.bin:8276 bytes";
  char *colonPos = strchr(linebuf,':'); // strchr returns the pointer of ":"
  cout<<colonPos<<endl;   // display: ":8276 bytes"
  cout<<*colonPos<<endl;  // display: ":"
  cout<<linebuf<<endl;   // display: "sortie.bin:8276 bytes"
  *colonPos = 0;
  cout<<linebuf<<endl;   // display :"sortie.bin"
  return 0;
```

}

My question is why: when I put `*colonPos = 0`, the linebuf change and all the things after ":" is canceled but I do not change anything of the linebuf in fact.

Comment: Why are you using the C library?

Answer (score 2):

`colonPos` is a pointer to the `:` character within `linebuf`.  When you replace the `:` with `\0`, you are "truncating" the string, because C strings are "null terminated" meaning by convention they stop at the first zero byte.

If you set the Nth character of a C string to `\0` (a zero byte), the string will then be at most N characters long.  This is how C strings are defined.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `*colonPos = 0` you modify the array to look like `"sortie.bin\08276 bytes"`. That is you replace the colon with the string terminator, and that replacement is a modification (or *change*) of `linebuf`.

Comment: Technically, it's `"sortie.bin\0008276 bytes"`, right?

Answer (score 0):

The operator `operator <<` overloaded for streams and objects of type `char *` (a character array used in expressions with rare exceptions is converted to pointer to its first element) outputs characters until the zero character is encountered. That is the operator considers character arrays as containing C strings.

If you want to output the whole array you should use method `write`. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

int main() 
{

    char linebuf[] = "sortie.bin:8276 bytes";
    size_t n = strlen( linebuf );

    char *colonPos = std::strchr( linebuf,':' ); 

    *colonPos = 0;

    std::cout.write( linebuf, n ) << std::endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
sortie.bin8276 bytes
```